# NGINX Reverse proxy with 3rd party apps

Tags: nginx

I'm using NGINX with a couple of 3rd party applications. I'm having an issue when the 3rd party app references a resource or link with a absolute path. If I owned the application I would be able to make changes to the paths to include the nginx location for each app but since I can't modify the 3rd party app i'm looking at the `nginx.conf` file for answers.

**nginx.conf**

```
location /app1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
}
location /app2/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
}
```

now in App1 and App2 they reference resources like this:

```
<img src='/images/app1_image.xyz'>
```

This causes the browser to look for the file at

```
http://domainname.com/images/app1_image.xyz
```

rather than

```
http://domainname.com/app1/images/app1_image.xyz
```

If I had one app I could just set the location to `/` but since I'm using nginx for multiple apps I believe each will need their own location. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: img was just an example. This applies to almost every resource in the app (href, js, css, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the use of `sub_filter` this fixed all the references in the html pages for each app.

```
location /app1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;

    sub_filter_once off;   
    sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/app1/';
    sub_filter "href='/" "href='/app1/";
    sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/app1/';
    sub_filter "src='/" "src='/app1/";
}

location /app2/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;

    sub_filter_once off;   
    sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/app2/';
    sub_filter "href='/" "href='/app2/";
    sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/app2/';
    sub_filter "src='/" "src='/app2/";
}
```